# Wordpress Arcade theme modification

Tags: wordpress

I'm self learning Wordpress and trying to modify Arcade basic theme.
What I need is to remove the ARCADE title and replace with an image. also I'm trying to get two call to action buttons instead one.

Can someone help me with a solution. I got a fair understanding about PHP however I seems to cant locate any file to think of a modification too.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your header.php file under the theme folder.

Open wp-content-> themes -> arcade-basic -> header.php

Put the following code under the

```
<div id="site-meta">
        <h1 id="site-title">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<URL to your LOGO>" /></a>                     </h1>

        <?php if ( $bavotasan_theme_options[ 'header_icon'] ) { ?>
        <i class="fa <?php echo $bavotasan_theme_options['header_icon']; ?>"></i>
        <?php } else { $space_class=' class="margin-top"' ; } ?>

        <h2 id="site-description" <?php echo $space_class; ?>>
                                <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>
                            </h2>
        <a href="#" id="more-site" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
            <?php _e( 'Button1', 'arcade' ); ?>
        </a>
        <a href="#" id="more-site" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
            <?php _e( 'Button2', 'arcade' ); ?>
        </a>
</div>
```

Let us know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can Change it Two Way.

**1.)** You Add Code On Direct Header.php Files.

```
   <div id="site-meta">
    <h1 id="site-title"> 
         <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
             <img src="<URL to your LOGO>" />
         </a>
   </h1>
```

This Code Is Dynamic Code It's Come From Admin Panel.And You Also Add Static Site Name Like

```
     <div id="site-meta">
       <h1 id="site-title">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="SITE NAME" rel="home"><img src="<URL to your LOGO>" />
        </a>
        </h1>
```

And Second Is.
**2).** Go Admin Panel -->> Appearance -->> Customize

**3).** you can create your own header.php file as per your requirement.

Now  You See Theme Setting Page Write Your SITE NAME  on Site Title & Tagline.